# How can I to toggle the text colors when I click the button twice?

Tags: javascript

I need to alternate the color of three numbers that contains the class '.holiday' and they are 24, 25 and 31. But with this code I get the image.[image] After the second click, the 24 and 31 change to red and 25 turn to blue.

```
let holidayClick = () => {
  const holidayBtn = document.querySelector('#btn-holiday');
  const holidayLi = document.querySelectorAll('.holiday');
  let isColored = false;

  for (let li of holidayLi) {
    holidayBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (isColored) {
        li.style.color = 'red';
        isColored = false;
      } else {
        li.style.color = 'blue';
        isColored = true;
      }
    });
  }
};
holidayClick();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in your code and stepping through it?

Comment: it looks like `isColored` is shared across all click handlers. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes I did. But I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
script.js:11
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you want to accomplish. But if you want to switch colors on certain `li`-elements, using some state (`isColored`), you can save the state in a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on a `li`-element. The event handler for the button has to be created once, in the snippet it is created at the document level ([event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation))

```js
document.addEventListener("click", holidayClick)

function holidayClick(evt) {
  // return if the click did not originate from the button
  if (evt.target.id !== "btn-holiday") { return; }
  
  // find all li /w attribute [data-holidaycolored] and
  // colorize them according to the value of the attribute
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-holidaycolored]').forEach(
    li => {
      const isColored = !!+li.dataset.holidaycolored;
      //                  ^ convert to number
      //                ^ convert number to boolean
      li.style.color = !isColored ? "blue" : "red";
      li.dataset.holidaycolored = +!isColored;
      //                          ^ flip boolean and convert to number
    });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li data-holidaycolored="0">21</li>
  <li data-holidaycolored="0">22</li>
  <li>23</li>
  <li>24</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li data-holidaycolored="0">31</li>
</ul>

<button id="btn-holiday">holidays</button>
```

It may also be that you want to colorize individual `li`-elements. In that case:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", holidayClick)

function holidayClick(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  
  // return if the click did not originate from the button
  if (!origin.dataset.colorholiday) { return; }
  
  // colorize the clicked element according to the value of the attribute
  const isColored = !!+origin.dataset.holidaycolored;
  origin.style.color = !isColored ? "blue" : "red";
  origin.dataset.holidaycolored = +!isColored;
}
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li data-colorholiday="0">21</li>
  <li data-colorholiday="0">22</li>
  <li data-colorholiday="0">23</li>
  <li data-colorholiday="0">24</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li data-colorholiday="0">31</li>
</ul>
```